# Send batch messages in Azure Service Bus arrives all in one message

Tags: rest, batch-processing, azureservicebus, send

In Azure, when I send a batch of messages to a queue, there arrives all in one message. I followed the instructions and example of the [Azure Service Bus REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-batch).

The curl call is something like this:

```
curl -X POST "https://{myServiceNamespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{name_of_my_queue}/messages" -v \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {my_token}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/vnd.microsoft.servicebus.json;" \
-d '[{"Body":"This is the first message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M1","TimeToLiveTimeSpan":"0.00:00:40"}},{"Body":"This is the second message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M2"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Low"}},{"Body":"This is the third message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M3"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Medium","Customer":"ABC"}}]'
```

The message arrives all in one:

[image]

Later, I tried some possible fixes, like change `TimeToLiveTimeSpan` property to `TimeToLive`, like indicates the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/introduction), but all were unsuccessful.

I suspect that the endpoint or the JSON structure must be different, but the documentation does not allow to know.

Someone knows why?

Comment: I'd suggest that the reason is that you have ALL of the messages selected in your `-d` parameter. I'd suggest you try multiple `-d` parameters, selecting one message in each. (I know nothing of `curl` - just my reading of the [documentation here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Thanks by the suggestion, @Magoo, but unfortunately it not works. Still arrives one only message, with the content concatenate by &: {"Body":"This is the first message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M1","TimeToLiveTimeSpan":"0.00:00:40"}}&{"Body":"This is the second message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M2"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Low"}}&{"Body":"This is the third message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M3"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Medium","Customer":"ABC"}}

Comment: Did you try `-d '[{"Body":"This is the first message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M1","TimeToLiveTimeSpan":"0.00:00:40"}}]'` newline 
`-d '[{"Body":"This is the second message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M2"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Low"}}]'` newline 
`-d '[{"Body":"This is the third message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M3"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Medium","Customer":"ABC"}}]'`?

Comment: I tried this: 
`-d '{"Body":"This is the first message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M1","TimeToLiveTimeSpan":"0.00:00:40"}}' \
-d '{"Body":"This is the second message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M2"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Low"}}' \
-d '{"Body":"This is the third message","BrokerProperties":{"Label":"M3"},"UserProperties":{"Priority":"Medium","Customer":"ABC"}}'`